# Learning Javascript (puppeteer)

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Im trying to learn to do some requests at the web, with javascript using puppeteer.

So i finally got from a random website, the value of tag a after some div.

But i dont know how to put this code in a "for" to get 10 values (10 tags a sequential).

This is how i got the value (Its working):

```
const resultado0 = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return document.querySelectorAll('.ui.divided.list > a')[0].textContent;
      });
      console.log(`O valor é ${resultado0}`);
```

How i tryied to do with for (Not working "ReferenceError: i is not defined"):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    const resultado = await page.evaluate(() => {
      return document.querySelectorAll('.ui.divided.list > a')[i].textContent;
    });
    console.log(`O valor é ${resultado}`);
  }
```

So i dont want to repeat the same code and put ([1],[2],[3],...), how can i do it?

Thanks

EDIT: FORGOT TO TELL THAT I CANT PRINT THE RESULT WITH querySelectorAll ITS RETURN UNDEFINED.
EX:

```
const resultado = await page.evaluate(() => {
      return document.querySelectorAll('.ui.divided.list > a').textContent;
    });
    console.log(`O valor é ${resultado[0]}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop *within* `page.evaluate` (different contexts), and even so, you'll get by easier with [`Array::map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
const resultado0 = await page.evaluate(() => {
  // Get the elements as a DOM node list
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".ui.divided.list > a");
  // Convert to an array we can map over, then map over to get the text content.
  return Array.from(elements).map((el) => el.textContent);
});
console.log(`O valor é ${resultado0}`);
```

Comment: Thanks, its working now. I'll for sure, search little more about "map".

Comment: Now is perfect => return Array.from(elements).slice(0,9).map((el) => el.textContent);

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem you have

you are using a await request without async function

see further details in this documentation :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

In the case where you console log the variable "resultado", the await is not yet resolved

```
const resultado = await page.evaluate(() => {
      return document.querySelectorAll('.ui.divided.list > a')[i].textContent;
    });
    console.log(`O valor é ${resultado}`);
```

Implement an async function that does that call may resolve your problem

Comment: Its in a async function, but its working now with AKX post. Thanks!